# Invalid attribute value inputToolkit:ButtonSpinner for property TargetType -While Xap Loading

Tags: .net, silverlight, c#-3.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

This Exception I got,

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled by user code
  Message="System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Invalid attribute value StylePalette for property Property. [Line: 6024 Position: 26]\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers, Boolean expandTemplatesDuringParse)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers)\r\n   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xaml)\r\n   at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ResourceParser.Parse(Stream stream, Boolean checkTypes)\r\n   at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Theme.LoadTheme(Stream themeResourceStream)\r\n   at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Theme..ctor(Assembly themeAssembly, String themeResourceName)\r\n   at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.TwilightBlueTheme..ctor() [Line: 0 Position: 0]\r\n   --- Inner Exception 
---\r\nInvalid attribute value StylePalette for property Property. [Line: 6024 Position: 26]\r\n"
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at SilverlightApplication7.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
       at SilverlightApplication7.MainPage..ctor(String ImagePath, String serviceUrl, String docId)
       at SilverlightImageApplication.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
       Message="Invalid attribute value StylePalette for property Property. [Line: 6024 Position: 26]"
       LineNumber=6024
       LinePosition=26
       StackTrace:
            at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers, Boolean expandTemplatesDuringParse)
            at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers)
            at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xaml)
            at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ResourceParser.Parse(Stream stream, Boolean checkTypes)
            at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Theme.LoadTheme(Stream themeResourceStream)
            at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Theme..ctor(Assembly themeAssembly, String themeResourceName)
            at System.Windows.Controls.Theming.TwilightBlueTheme..ctor()
       InnerException:
```

I am using
Visual Studio 2008,
Silverlight 3.0,
Silverlight Toolkit July 2009,
Silverlight Tools for VS 2008 SP1.

Comment: Can you show the the Xaml where the ButtonSpinner is being used?  I might be useful for us to actually be able to see what value have assigned the TargetType.

Comment: I nerver use this inputToolkit:ButtonSpinner in my silverlight app, I search this term in Entire Solution. Can not find inputToolkit:ButtonSpinner. But the Same Solution is working in other mechine.I can not able to understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the user settings in visual studio , by importing some VsSettings or by changing the debug settings manually.

**Please revert to the default visual C# settings in the Visual Studio IDE.Tools->Import and Export Settings-> Reset All settings**

The SL styling elements usually swallows certain exceptions.Your debug settings might be strict :)

This trick worked for me, please update if still not working for you.

Thanks,
Vijay.